# EmberJs - How to go about creating a plugin for EmberJs

Tags: ember.js

This might be a broad question, but I'm looking at:
Is there a part of the Ember API that provide some facility to create extensions?
Any existing plugins that show a good approach to it?

Thanks!,

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot built into Ember.js to extend functionality, as a lot of the classes can be extended, which is the standard way of building your own controllers, routes, and models; and existing classes, and existing instances can both be "reopened". [It might be better to ask specifically what you want to achieve for a more specific answer on a good way to go about doing it.]

Also, if you want to have a completely new class that defines behaviour that your controllers or routes need access to, then there is a mechanism where you can inject an instance of your new class into them, without the instance being a global variable. Based on the code from http://livsey.org/blog/2013/02/10/integrating-pusher-with-ember/ , you can define the class by:

```
Ember.MyNewPlugin = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    // Anything you need to do to initialise the object
  },
  myFunc: function(param) {
    // Anything you need to do with with "param"
  }
});
```

And then inject the instance into controllers and routes by:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: "mynewplugin",
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    // use the same instance everywhere in the app
    container.optionsForType('mynewplugin', { singleton: true });

    // register 'mynewplugin:main' as our MyNewPlugin object
    container.register('mynewplugin', 'main', Ember.MyNewPlugin);

    // inject the MyNewPlugin object into all controllers and routes
    container.typeInjection('controller', 'mynewplugin', 'mynewplugin:main');
    container.typeInjection('route', 'mynewplugin', 'mynewplugin:main');
  }
});
```

Then in controllers and routes you can access the instance by

```
var myNewPlugin = this.get('mynewplugin');
```

And call its functions by:

```
myNewPlugin("Some data");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special you need to in oder to add "extensions" to Ember. The most likely thing you will want to do is introduce new `Controllers and Views`. In order to do so, you just have to subclass the core classes of Ember. [Here](https://github.com/emberjs/list-view/tree/master/packages/list-view/lib) is an example of such an "extension", which provides views, that are reusable and provide lots of value.